# Get Country/Province list from Google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Is there a jQuery plugin that i can user to retrieve simple list of Countries from Google Maps? 
Id also like to be able to send Google Maps a country name, and it needs to return a list of that countries provinces/states, or something similar.

Thanks In advance, 
Grant

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to auto-fill country/place name on google maps? If you want

Check it [Geocomplete](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/)

work like this;

[image]